# Chrome Dev tools - why are these elements on an empty page?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging with the Chrome Dev tools and looking at a memory timeline.  I have simplified my page so that it contains only this:

```
<html>
</html>
```

Yet I have two Documents, 64 Nodes and 6 listeners!  What are these and where do they come from?  I am in incognito mode to remove extraneous items.

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you View/Source?

Comment: Are you running any Chrome extensions?

Comment: View source jusit shows <HTML><HEADER><BODY></BODY></HEADER></HTML>, as expected.  No extensions - I'm incognito.

Answer (score 3):

It's very likely that you're using a Chrome extension that's running in the background. A large number of extensions will inject HTML and occasionally CSS/JS into the current page in order to function. For example, in order to enable some additional sharing functionality or the ability to capture what the current tab looks like.

When testing it's best to open up a new Incognito window or blank user profile where these extensions won't affect your view of the DOM in DevTools.